# apache security

Tags: facebook, apache, security, debugging

I need to use a facebook application but my web page return response 206 instead 200,
so that the facebook application return http code 500.

I tested with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://adserver.leadhouse.net/test/test/index.php and return 206 instead joomla.it return 200
when they are same curl -I response datae

I tested with this perl script: http://pastebin.com/NCDv9eTh
and my page is vulnerable instead joomla.it is good.

I think that my answer is very close between
[Facebook debugger : Response 206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807771/facebook-debugger-response-206)
and [Apache Webserver security and optimization tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171237/apache-webserver-security-and-optimization-tips)

but I don't understand how change my apache configuration.
the solution is into this page:
www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2
with similar code:

```
    SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
    RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range
```

or
httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize

how can I make it less vulnerable to my web pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everything is started with debugging facebook: dialog send return 500 http code with my page return 206 http code.
And my curiosity is focused on DoS vulnerability of http code 206 when I tested perl script http://pastebin.com/NCDv9eTh

I report some significant phrase about apache documentation:

> This vulnerability concerns a 'Denial of Service' attack. This means
>   that a remote attacker, under the right circumstances, is able to slow
>   your service or server down to a crawl or exhausting memory available
>   to serve requests, leaving it unable to serve legitimate clients in a
>   timely manner.
>
> There are no indications that this leads to a remote exploit; where a
>   third party can compromise your security and gain foothold of the
>   server itself. The result of this vulnerability is purely one of
>   denying service by grinding your server down to a halt and refusing
>   additional connections to the server.

so that `LimitRequestFieldSize` workaround was insufficient,
you could modify `Range` parameters consulting `Mitigation` paragraph
about apache wiki documentation: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CVE-2011-3192
You obtain switch between return http code: from 206 to 200.
You best apache configuration, but you're still exposed to DoS vulnerability.

I added `mod_headers` with this line:

```
RequestHeader unset Range
```

and now my page return http code 200.
And to limit exhausting memory available to serve requests,
I limit ip connections adding `mod_limitipconn` with this code:

```
MaxConnPerIP 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what kind of “vulnerability” you are talking about here.

Facebook debugger showing a response status code 206 is *normal* – because the debugger tries to only request the first *x* (K)Bytes from your URL. If your server accepts such range requests and answers them correctly, then the response code will be 206.

There **is** no *vulnerability* in that.

If this causes you any *other* problems with your site – then please describe them in a manner that makes them comprehensible.

Comment: I create a web facebook application to dialog/send message but my web page return response 206 instead 200, so that the facebook application return http code 500. I would like that my page return response 200 instead 206 because I think the facebook application should return 200 and not 500. is that correct?